# Extracting text between two bookmarks using Apache PdfBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox to read a PDF document that has a hierarchy defined by bookmarks. The hierarchy is in a tree form with contents only at the leaf level.

Extracting the text between two leaf level bookmarks using the following code:

```
Stripper.setStartBookmark(), 
Stripper.setEndBookmark(),
Stripper.writeText()),
```

Returns text in the whole page instead. In short, my problem is similar to that mentioned in [this thread](http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/51032-pdox-1-6-0-extract-text-between-2-bookmarks-same-page-sos.html).

Is there a way to extract the contents between two bookmarks?

If so, what should be the change in my code?

Comment: @Shiram -I have same question. please post the answer if you have already figured it out

Comment: Did you find a solution? If not do you have an example of the bookmark (for example, in XML format).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your bookmark does not contain the correct data.

It sounds like the bookmark you are using is only pointing to the **page** where your content starts, rather than a **location** on the page.

Here is an example of a bookmark that contains location data:

```
<Title Action="GoTo" Style="bold" Page="2 FitH 518">
Title Name
</Title>
```

Comment: In PDFBox, the bookmarks are resolved to a PDPageXYZDestination, as a result of specific GoTo actions from the bookmarks. So, they do indeed point to an absolute position in the page, which is verified in my PDF viewer, where clicking on a bookmark scrolls directly to section.